# gluPerspective() displaying a black screen?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I have a simple application that displays a 3D cube that rotates on all axes, and a camera controlled via mouse that allows you to adjust the angle you're looking at the cube.

The entire application works exactly as I want when I use glOrtho, but once I change it to gluPerspective I only get a black screen.

Here is my method to initialize openGL:

```
public void initializeOpenGL()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float)WIDTH) / ((float)HEIGHT), 0.01f, 500f);
    //glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 600, -1); //displays everything correctly
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

And then here is my loop method:

```
public void begin()
{
    float degrees = 0;
    Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
    while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {
        moveCamera(); //calculates the changes in mouse position            
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.lookThrough(); //applies the changes
        glTranslatef((float)WIDTH/2,(float)HEIGHT/2,10f);
        glRotatef(degrees++,1f,1f,1f);
        glScalef(100,100,100);

        drawQuad();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);     
}
```

Comment: The values passed to your orthographic projection matrix flips the Z-axis (the Y-axis too, but that is not a big deal that will only affect polygon winding). You should consider translating by **z = -10f** when you use perspective projection so that your object is in front of the near plane.

Comment: There is also the issue of your depth test direction. You may need to use `glDepthRange (1.0f, 0.0f);` if you actually inverted your near/far plane on purpose.

Comment: This all depends on the range of coordinates you're drawing, and what transformation your `camera` applies. With the `gluProjection()` call you're making, you need to move your geometry so that it's visible when looking down the negative z-axis from the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an image displaying where the camera looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIPhm.png
As you can see the camera looks along the -z axis

-> you should try translating the quad to something like:

```
glTranslatef(0,0, -10f );
```

Instead of moving the quad to the middle of the Display you move it half the size of the Display in the nowhere of your Landscape

**SHORT VERSION:** Gist: https://gist.github.com/Chronove/11da12b2635bfc040981

```
package me.tutorial;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

/**
 * @author Chronove
 */
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int WIDTH  = 600;
        int HEIGHT = 400;

        // INIT
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        Display.create();

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluPerspective(45.0f,(float)(WIDTH / HEIGHT),0.1f,500f);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        float degrees = 0;

        while(!(Display.isCloseRequested())){

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glLoadIdentity();

            glTranslatef(0,0,-10f);
            glRotatef(degrees++,0f,0f,1f);

            // drawQuad();
            {

                glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glVertex3f(-1f,-1f,0f);
                glVertex3f( 1f,-1f,0f);
                glVertex3f( 1f, 1f,0f);
                glVertex3f(-1f, 1f,0f);

                glEnd();

            }

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }

        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh OH OH! I get it now! I'm gonna try this and see if it works! :D

Comment: So I went back into my original class and adjusted my translation to what you had, and it worked! Thanks so muchC: